# OOP Java How do I check an array against another array and replace the data if the other array has higher numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I am trying to check the selected enemy's weapons and armor to see if they are better than the main character's. So, I want to check each one by one, and if the enemy's are better I want to set the main character's weapon equal to the enemy's to basically take it and it to the main character's bag. Everything I have tried so far has been checking to see if one weapon is better and replacing all weapon regardless if the others are better or not. Is there a way I can check each individually?

I have four classes. Main. Character. Weapon. Armor. This is the part of the main class where I am trying to switch:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import Character.Character;

import java.util.Random;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("> Welcome to The Game Project <");
    System.out.println("\n >> Input Main Character Name: ");
    String main_name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(">> Input Main Character Power: ");
    int main_power=scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(">> Input Main Character Hp: ");
    int main_hp=scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");

    Character main_ch=new Character (main_hp,main_power,main_name);
    show_status(main_ch);
    check_bag(main_ch);

    Character enemies[]=new Character [10];
    enemies[0]= new Character("Werewolf");
    enemies[1]= new Character("Vampire");
    enemies[2]= new Character("Alien");
    enemies[3]= new Character("Witch");
    enemies[4]= new Character("Ghost");
    enemies[5]= new Character("Skeleton");
    enemies[6]= new Character("Zombie");
    enemies[7]= new Character("Demon");
    enemies[8]= new Character("Mummy");
    enemies[9]= new Character("Dragon");

    boolean check = false;

    int dead_count=0;
    while(true) {

        Random rnd=new Random();
        int selected = rnd.nextInt(enemies.length); //random enemy selected

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>>>> An enemy has appeared! <<<<<");
            while(enemies[selected].getHp()>0) { 
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(">>>>> "+enemies[selected].getName()+" wants to fight!");
                show_status(enemies[selected]);
                check_bag(enemies[selected]);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(">> What do you want to do?");
                System.out.println("\t1. Fight!");
                System.out.println("\t2. Use skill.");
                System.out.println("\t3. Check your stats.");
                int input = scanner.nextInt();

                    if(input==1) {
// originally using                     int damageToEnemy = rnd.nextInt(main_ch.hit_point());
// originally using                     int damageTaken = rnd.nextInt(enemies[selected].hit_point());

                            int damageToEnemy = main_ch.hit_point();
                            int damageTaken = enemies[selected].hit_point();
                            enemies[selected].hp -= damageToEnemy;
                            main_ch.hp -= damageTaken;
                            if(enemies[selected].hp <= 0) {
                                enemies[selected].hp=0;
                                   dead_count=dead_count+1;
                                main_ch.level=main_ch.level+1; //gain one level after enemy defeated
                                System.out.println(">> You defeated the enemy and gained a level!");

                                main_ch.getBag().setMoney(main_ch.getBag().getMoney() + enemies[selected].getBag().getMoney());//take defeated enemy's money
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("\t>> You found "+enemies[selected].getBag().getMoney()+" dollars. You now have "+main_ch.getBag().getMoney()+" dollars in your bag."); 



                                    if(enemies[selected].getWeapon().getPower() > main_ch.getWeapon().getPower()) { //check to see if enemy's weapons have higher power
                                        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {      
                                        main_ch.getBag().setWeaponArray(i, enemies[selected].getBag().getWeaponArray()[i]); //replace weapons if they are better
                                    }
                                        System.out.println("\t>> You found better weapons! They have been added to your bag.");
                                    }

                                    if(enemies[selected].getArmor().getDefense() > main_ch.getArmor().getDefense()) {   //check to see if enemy's armor is better
                                        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {  
                                        main_ch.getBag().setArmorArray(i, enemies[selected].getBag().getArmorArray()[i]); //replace armor if it is better
                                    }
                                        System.out.println("\t>> You found better armor! They have been added to your bag.");
                                    }
                                break;

                            }
                            System.out.println("\n>> You caused "+ damageToEnemy +" damage to the enemy! Their hp is now "+ enemies[selected].hp+".");
                            System.out.println(">> You received "+ damageTaken +" damage from the enemy! Your hp is now "+main_ch.hp+".");

                            if(main_ch.hp <=0) {
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println(">> Oh no! You died! Better luck next time. Thanks for playing!");
                                System.out.println();
                            break;
                            }   

                        }

                    else if(input==2) {
                        if(main_ch.getSkill()>0 && main_ch.getMp()>0) {
                            main_ch.useSkill();
                            System.out.println("\t>> You used a skill. Your hit point increased to "+main_ch.hit_point()+". Your MP decreased to "+main_ch.getMp()+".");
                        }
                        else {
                            if(main_ch.getSkill()<=0) {
                                System.out.println("You have no skill points left.");
                            }
                            else{
                            System.out.println("\t>> Your MP is too low to use skill.");
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    else if(input==3) {
                        System.out.println();
                        show_status(main_ch);
                        check_bag(main_ch);                                             
                        }
                    else {
                        System.out.println(">> You have entered an invalid key.");

                    }
                    }



            if(dead_count==enemies.length) {
                check=true;
            }
            if(check) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> You won! Congratulations, you defeated all of your enemies! <<<<<<<<<");
                break;
           }
            if(main_ch.hp <=0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(">> Oh no! You died! Better luck next time. Thanks for playing!");
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }



            }
        }
public static void show_status(Character character) {
    System.out.println("----------------- Character Status -----------------");
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Name:\t\t"+character.getName());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter HP:\t\t"+character.getHp());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Power:\t"+character.getPower());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Defense:\t"+character.getDefense());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter MP:\t\t"+character.getMp());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Level:\t"+character.getLevel());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Hit Point:\t"+character.hit_point());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Skill:\t"+character.getSkill());
    System.out.println("\tWeapon Name:\t\t"+character.getWeapon().getName());
    System.out.println("\tWeapon Power:\t\t"+character.getWeapon().getPower());
    System.out.println("\tArmor Name:\t\t"+character.getArmor().getName());
    System.out.println("\tArmor Defense:\t\t"+character.getArmor().getDefense());
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
}
public static void check_bag(Character character) {
    System.out.println("-------------------- Bag Status --------------------");
    System.out.println("\tMoney:\t\t\t$"+ character.getBag().getMoney());
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        System.out.println("\tWeapon Name/Power:\t"+ character.getBag().getWeaponArray()[i].getName()+" // "+character.getBag().getWeaponArray()[i].getPower());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        System.out.println("\tArmor  Name/Defense:\t"+ character.getBag().getArmorArray()[i].getName()+" // "+character.getBag().getArmorArray()[i].getDefense());
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
}

}
```

This is the Character class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import Equipment.*;

public class Character {
    private Armor armor = new Armor();
    private Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
    private Bag bag = new Bag();

    public static String server_name = "CS172";
    public int hp, power, defense, mp, level, skill;
    private String name;
    Random rnd=new Random(); 

    public Character(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        Random rnd=new Random();
        this.hp=rnd.nextInt(500)+1;
        this.power=rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.defense=rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.mp=rnd.nextInt(50)+1;
        this.level=1;
        this.skill=5;
}
    public Character(int hp, int power, String name) {
        this.hp=hp;
        this.power=power;
        this.name=name;
        this.defense=rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.mp=rnd.nextInt(50)+1;
        this.level=1;
        this.skill=5;
}
    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
}
    public void setHp(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
}
    public int getPower() {
        return power;
}
    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
}
    public int getDefense() {
        return defense;
}
    public void setDefense(int defense) {
        this.defense = defense;
}
    public int getMp() {
        return mp;
}
    public void setMp(int mp) {
        this.mp = mp;
}
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
}
    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
}
    public int damage(int enemy_power) {
        int damage = enemy_power - this.defense;
        if(damage<0){ //avoid healing by damage
            damage=0;
}
        this.hp=this.hp - damage;
        if(this.hp<0) { //avoid negative hp
            this.hp = 0;
}
        return damage;
}

    public Armor getArmor() {
    return armor;
}
    public void setArmor(Armor armor) {
        this.armor = armor;
}
    public Weapon getWeapon() {
        return weapon;
}
    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
}
    public int hit_point() {
        int total_power = this.power + this.weapon.getPower();
        return total_power;
    }
    public int useSkill() {
        this.mp=this.mp-1;
        this.skill--;
        this.power =this.power + 30;
        return hit_point();
    }
    public int getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public Bag getBag() {
        return bag;
    }
    public void setBag(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    public class Bag{
        Weapon weaponArray[] = new Weapon[4];
        Armor armorArray[] = new Armor[4];
        int money = 150;
        public Bag(){
            for(int i=0; i<weaponArray.length; i++) {
                weaponArray[i] = new Weapon();
                armorArray[i] = new Armor();
            }
        }
        public Weapon[] getWeaponArray() {
            return weaponArray;
        }
        public void setWeaponArray(int yourWeaponIndex, Weapon enemyWeapon) {
            this.weaponArray[yourWeaponIndex] = enemyWeapon;
        }
        public Armor[] getArmorArray() {
            return armorArray;
        }
        public void setArmorArray(int yourArmorIndex, Armor enemyArmor) {
            this.armorArray[yourArmorIndex] = enemyArmor;
        }
//      public void setArmorArray(Armor[] armorArray) {
//          this.armorArray = armorArray;
//      }
        public int getMoney() {
            return money;
        }
        public void setMoney(int money) {
            this.money = money;
        }

    }
}
```

I am doing this for a class, and we wrote part of the code in class with the professor. I have a feeling I am supposed to use this somehow, but I don't even really understand what it is doing:

```
public void setWeaponArray(int yourWeaponIndex, Weapon enemyWeapon) {
                this.weaponArray[yourWeaponIndex] = enemyWeapon;
}
```

Can someone explain this to me please?

Weapons class:

```
package Equipment;
import java.util.Random;

public class Weapon {
    private String name;
    private int power;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public Weapon() {
        this.name="Weapon #" + rnd.nextInt(20);
        this.power=rnd.nextInt(50)+1;
}
    public Weapon(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        this.power=rnd.nextInt(50)+1;
}
    public int getPower() {
        return power;
}
    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
}
    public String getName() {
        return name;
}

}
```

Armor class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Armor {
    private String name;
    private int defense;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public Armor() {
        this.name="Armor #"+rnd.nextInt(10);
        this.defense=rnd.nextInt(10)+1;
}
    public Armor(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        this.defense=rnd.nextInt(10)+1;
}
    public int getDefense() {
        return defense;
}
    public void setDefense(int defense) {
        this.defense = defense;
}
    public String getName() {
        return name;
}
}
```

Comment: In OOP there are Getters and Setters, with the getters you obtain the information you need and with the set you update the variable. The setWeaponArray is the method you need to use if you want to change the weapon you are actually using. If you see the parameters, first of all you need to give the index of your weapon that you want to change, then you must give the weapon you selected from your enemy. Once you've find out which weapon is better than yours and you have got it with the get method, you have to use the method to set it to your actual weapon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the whole bag array just replace the weapon at the specific index in the loop.

You are almost there... That method that you wanted to use is exactly used for what you want. It is a method that requires two things. The position of your weapon to be replaced (yourWeaponIndex) and the item to replace it with (enemyWeapon). The weapons loop you are replacing the whole bag instead of the weapon in question.

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {      //loop through your items one by one
    for(int j = 0; j<4; j++) {      //loop through enemy items one by one

        //compare item 1 to all 4 enemies items (order 16 comparison - 4 x 4 comparisons)
        if(enemies[selected].getBag().getWeaponArray()[j].getPower() > main_ch.getBag().getWeaponArray()[i].getPower()) { //check to see if enemy's weapons have higher power
            //put stronger enemy weapon (j) in your bag
            main_ch.getBag().setWeaponArray(i, enemies[selected].getBag().getWeaponArray()[j]); 
            //put your weaker weapon (i) in enemy bag
            enemies[selected].getBag().setWeaponArray(j, main_ch.getBag().getWeaponArray()[i]); 
            //alert that items have changed
            System.out.println("\t>> You found better weapons! They have been added to your bag.");
        }
    }
}
```

For the purpose of interest and learning

```
for(int k = 0; k<4; k++) {      //loop through your items one by one
    for(int l = 0; l<4; l++) {          //loop through enemy items one by one

        //compare item 1 to all 4 enemies items (order 16 comparison - 4 x 4 comparisons)
        if(enemies[selected].getBag().getArmorArray()[l].getDefense() > main_ch.getBag().getArmorArray()[k].getDefense()) { //check to see if enemy's armor has higher power
           //put stronger enemy armor in your bag
           main_ch.getBag().setArmorArray(k, enemies[selected].getBag().getArmorArray()[l]); 
           //put your weaker armor in enemy bag
           enemies[selected].getBag().setArmorArray(l, main_ch.getBag().getArmorArray()[k]); 
           //alert that items have changed
           System.out.println("\t>> You found better weapons! They have been added to your bag.");
        }
    }
}
```

See the working code:
https://onlinegdb.com/rkg3n7ICH

Comment: Thank you! This is starting to make sense. However, when I change the code to include the i parameter and it is still replacing all weapons if just one is of a higher power. :/

Comment: This is where the debugger comes in. I would suggest you put a break point on the loop and run through each iteration to see where it goes wrong. Debugging and planning are key to development.

The benefit of using one of the newer code editors/IDEs is that they are built with debugging tools. If you are unsure about how to use the debugger ask your professor to do a quick lesson on it.

As a side note: can you include all of the files in this project?

Comment: I will try using the debugger. I'll watch some videos on it because I'm not completely sure how to use it. Also, I updated my original post with all of the code.

Comment: If you still are unsure using a debugger then try a trace table with pen and paper first.

https://www.101computing.net/using-trace-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you are providing

```
public void setWeaponArray(int yourWeaponIndex, Weapon enemyWeapon) {
        this.weaponArray[yourWeaponIndex] = enemyWeapon;
    }
```

This method sets the current weapon of the bag (Your object here is the bag) to another enemyWeapon using the index of the element in the array  `weaponArray[]` . But, since your array length is 4, I believe you have to call it 4 times to make the 4 weapons in the bag.

```
main_ch.getBag().setWeaponArray(enemies[selected].getBag().getWeaponArray());
```

In this line, you are not specifying the index (You normally have 2 parameters for the method setWeapon(int yourWeaponIndex, Weapon enemyWeapon)

It should be **something like this** :

```
main_ch.getBag().setWeaponArray(i ,enemies[selected].getBag().getWeaponArray());
```

i is the index of the weapon to change.

*Example*

```
main_ch.getBag().setWeaponArray(0 ,enemies[selected].getBag().getWeaponArray() );
```

This line only changes the first weapon if the enemy's weapon is better.

Comment: The setWeaponArray(int yourWeaponIndex, Weapon enemyWeapon) method replaces the weapon at the specified index. In your post you have used the weapon array as the second parameter instead of the weapon Object to be replaced. The name of the method is probably a bit confusing but that is another issue on its own.

Comment: each element of this array refers to an object, and that's not the weapon array, that's the enemies : each element of this array refers to an object. Yeah, like you said, the names are a quite confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I use this code: main_ch.getBag().setWeaponArray(i ,enemies[selected].getBag().getWeaponArray()); I get an error because it's looking for [i] at the end. But if I add [i], it replaces all of the weapons in the array if just one has a higher power.

Comment: what do you mean by 'looking for [i] at the end' ? an ArrayOutOfBounds error you mean?

Comment: I get this error when I don't include [i]: "The method setWeaponArray(int, Weapon) in the type Character.Bag is not applicable for the arguments (int, Weapon[])."

Comment: Like I said initially the second parameter wants the weapon object. The array at position [i] will give that weapon object to be replaced.

Comment: I was reading your code after the edit you made, I realized that you are creating a new Weapon and a new Bag at the same time. That's propably the problem, because the iteration and the if condition works fine. The confusing part is the fact that you are creating a weapon and a bag in class Character, however, in class Bag you have a Weapon Array, you either choose one of those practice, not both.